# unfortunately application stopped and runtime exception main no classdef found error

Tags: android

Hi friends I am new to the android programming. My application closes when I try to retrieve data from a URL. I am taking only title, date_taken and media tags from the url file. help me

listview activity
        package com.suni.sun;

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import com.suni.sun.JsonParse;
import com.suni.sun.HomeGv;


public class ListViewActivity extends Activity  {

    private ListView lv;
    private ArrayList<HomeGv> img;
    private ArrayAdapter<HomeGv> adap;

    private final static String TAG = ListViewActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private final static String url = "http://saicloudica.cloudapp.net/json.txt";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        setListViewAdapter();
        getDataFromInternet();
    }

    private void getDataFromInternet(){
        new JsonParse(this, url).execute();
    }

    private void setListViewAdapter(){
        img = new ArrayList<HomeGv>();
        adap = new CustomListViewAdapter(this, R.layout.home_item, img);
        lv.setAdapter(adap);
    }

    public void parseJsonResponse(String result){
        Log.i(TAG, result);
        try{
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(json.getString("items"));
            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++){
                JSONObject jObj = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                HomeGv imgs = new HomeGv();
                imgs.setTitle(jObj.getString("title"));
                imgs.setDate(jObj.getString("date_taken"));
                if(json.has("media")) 
                { 
                    JSONObject media = jObj.getJSONObject("media"); 
                    if(null != media && media.length() > 0) 
                    { 
                        String medi = media.getString("m"); 
                        if(medi != null)
                        { 
                            imgs.setMedia(media.getString("m")); 
                        }
                    }
                }


                img.add(imgs);
            }
            adap.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } catch (JSONException e){

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.putExtra("EXIT", true);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

jsonparse class

```
package com.suni.sun;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

import com.suni.sun.ListViewActivity;

public class JsonParse extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    private Activity activity;
    private String url;
    private ProgressDialog dialog;

    private final static String TAG = JsonParse.class.getSimpleName();

    public JsonParse(Activity activity, String url)
    {
        super();
        this.activity = activity;   
        this.url = url;     
    }



    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();

        dialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);

        dialog.setTitle("Getting Json Data");

        dialog.setMessage("Loading");

        dialog.setIndeterminate(false);

        dialog.show();
    }



    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return loadJSON(this.url).toString();
    }



    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ((ListViewActivity) activity).parseJsonResponse(result);
        dialog.dismiss();
        Log.i(TAG, result);
    }


    private JSONObject loadJSON(String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JSONGetter jParser = new JSONGetter();

        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
        return json;
    }

       private class JSONGetter {

        private InputStream is = null;
        private JSONObject jObj = null;
        private String json = "";

        // constructor
        public JSONGetter() {

        }

        public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

            // Making HTTP request
            try {
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"),
                        8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                json = sb.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
            } 

            // try parse the string to a JSON object
            try {
                jObj = new JSONObject(json);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
            }

            // return JSON String
            return jObj;
        }
       }

}
```

customlistviewadapter

```
package com.suni.sun;

import java.util.List;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
import com.suni.sun.HomeGv;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<HomeGv> {

    private Activity activity;

    public CustomListViewAdapter(Activity activity, int resource,
            List<HomeGv> img) {
        super(activity, resource, img);
        this.activity = activity;
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        ViewHolder holder = null;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_item, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);

        }else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        HomeGv thing = (HomeGv) getItem(position);

        holder.title.setText(thing.getTitle());
        holder.date_taken.setText(thing.getDate());
        Picasso.with(activity).load(thing.getMedia()).into(holder.image);

        return convertView;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        private TextView title,date_taken;
        private ImageView image;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_title);
            date_taken = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_date);
            image = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);
        }
    }

}
```

my Home class

package com.suni.sun;

```
public class HomeGv {

    private String title;
    private String media;
    private String date_taken;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public String getMedia() {
        return media;
    }
    public void setMedia(String m) {
        this.media = m;
    }
    public String getDate() {
        return date_taken;
    }
    public void setDate(String date_taken) {
        this.date_taken = date_taken;
    }
}
```

and my url file

```
{
    "title": "Recent Uploads tagged soccer",
    "link": "http://www.flickr.com/photos/tags/soccer/",
    "description": "",
    "modified": "2015-09-28T02:59:30Z",
    "generator": "http://www.flickr.com/",
    "items": [
        {
            "title": "IMG_9207",
            "link": "http://www.flickr.com/photos/sportclubsilvolde/21782884471/",
            "media": {
                "m": "http://farm1.staticflickr.com/681/21782884471_6834f2c9d8_m.jpg"
            },
            "date_taken": "2015-09-27T15:00:50-08:00",
            "description": " <p><a href=\"http://www.flickr.com/people/sportclubsilvolde/\">SportclubSilvolde</a> posted a photo:</p> <p><a href=\"http://www.flickr.com/photos/sportclubsilvolde/21782884471/\" title=\"IMG_9207\"><img src=\"http://farm1.staticflickr.com/681/21782884471_6834f2c9d8_m.jpg\" width=\"240\" height=\"160\" alt=\"IMG_9207\" /></a></p> ",
            "published": "2015-09-28T02:59:30Z",
            "author": "nobody@flickr.com (SportclubSilvolde)",
            "author_id": "124810748@N04",
            "tags": "iris copyright sports soccer be quick epping voetbal 2015 1887 sportclub silvolde hoofdklasse"
        },
        {
            "title": "IMG_9484",
            "link": "http://www.flickr.com/photos/sportclubsilvolde/21747301246/",
            "media": {
                "m": "http://farm1.staticflickr.com/736/21747301246_f03bc953d6_m.jpg"
            },
            "date_taken": "2015-09-27T15:58:43-08:00",
            "description": " <p><a href=\"http://www.flickr.com/people/sportclubsilvolde/\">SportclubSilvolde</a> posted a photo:</p> <p><a href=\"http://www.flickr.com/photos/sportclubsilvolde/21747301246/\" title=\"IMG_9484\"><img src=\"http://farm1.staticflickr.com/736/21747301246_f03bc953d6_m.jpg\" width=\"240\" height=\"160\" alt=\"IMG_9484\" /></a></p> ",
            "published": "2015-09-28T02:59:38Z",
            "author": "nobody@flickr.com (SportclubSilvolde)",
            "author_id": "124810748@N04",
            "tags": "iris copyright sports soccer be quick epping voetbal 2015 1887 sportclub silvolde hoofdklasse"
        },
        {
            "title": "IMG_9135",
            "link": "http://www.flickr.com/photos/sportclubsilvolde/21585600568/",
            "media": {
                "m": "http://farm1.staticflickr.com/588/21585600568_bce2bcd47a_m.jpg"
            },
            "date_taken": "2015-09-27T14:53:53-08:00",
            "description": " <p><a href=\"http://www.flickr.com/people/sportclubsilvolde/\">SportclubSilvolde</a> posted a photo:</p> <p><a href=\"http://www.flickr.com/photos/sportclubsilvolde/21585600568/\" title=\"IMG_9135\"><img src=\"http://farm1.staticflickr.com/588/21585600568_bce2bcd47a_m.jpg\" width=\"240\" height=\"160\" alt=\"IMG_9135\" /></a></p> ",
            "published": "2015-09-28T02:59:28Z",
            "author": "nobody@flickr.com (SportclubSilvolde)",
            "author_id": "124810748@N04",
            "tags": "iris copyright sports soccer be quick epping voetbal 2015 1887 sportclub silvolde hoofdklasse"
        },
        {
            "title": "IMG_9062",
            "link": "http://www.flickr.com/photos/sportclubsilvolde/21761757502/",
            "media": {
                "m": "http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5648/21761757502_e18ee1b76f_m.jpg"
            },
            "date_taken": "2015-09-27T14:48:06-08:00",
            "description": " <p><a href=\"http://www.flickr.com/people/sportclubsilvolde/\">SportclubSilvolde</a> posted a photo:</p> <p><a href=\"http://www.flickr.com/photos/sportclubsilvolde/21761757502/\" title=\"IMG_9062\"><img src=\"http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5648/21761757502_e18ee1b76f_m.jpg\" width=\"240\" height=\"160\" alt=\"IMG_9062\" /></a></p> ",
            "published": "2015-09-28T02:59:27Z",
            "author": "nobody@flickr.com (SportclubSilvolde)",
            "author_id": "124810748@N04",
            "tags": "iris copyright sports soccer be quick epping voetbal 2015 1887 sportclub silvolde hoofdklasse"
        },
        {
            "title": "IMG_9718",
            "link": "http://www.flickr.com/photos/sportclubsilvolde/21773428785/",
            "media": {
                "m": "http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5798/21773428785_256689c88f_m.jpg"
            },
            "date_taken": "2015-09-27T16:27:04-08:00",
            "description": " <p><a href=\"http://www.flickr.com/people/sportclubsilvolde/\">SportclubSilvolde</a> posted a photo:</p> <p><a href=\"http://www.flickr.com/photos/sportclubsilvolde/21773428785/\" title=\"IMG_9718\"><img src=\"http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5798/21773428785_256689c88f_m.jpg\" width=\"240\" height=\"160\" alt=\"IMG_9718\" /></a></p> ",
            "published": "2015-09-28T02:59:43Z",
            "author": "nobody@flickr.com (SportclubSilvolde)",
            "author_id": "124810748@N04",
            "tags": "iris copyright sports soccer be quick epping voetbal 2015 1887 sportclub silvolde hoofdklasse"
        },
        {
            "title": "IMG_9279",
            "link": "http://www.flickr.com/photos/sportclubsilvolde/21761743622/",
            "media": {
                "m": "http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5663/21761743622_1787fff746_m.jpg"
            },
            "date_taken": "2015-09-27T15:15:23-08:00",
            "description": " <p><a href=\"http://www.flickr.com/people/sportclubsilvolde/\">SportclubSilvolde</a> posted a photo:</p> <p><a href=\"http://www.flickr.com/photos/sportclubsilvolde/21761743622/\" title=\"IMG_9279\"><img src=\"http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5663/21761743622_1787fff746_m.jpg\" width=\"240\" height=\"160\" alt=\"IMG_9279\" /></a></p> ",
            "published": "2015-09-28T02:59:34Z",
            "author": "nobody@flickr.com (SportclubSilvolde)",
            "author_id": "124810748@N04",
            "tags": "iris copyright sports soccer be quick epping voetbal 2015 1887 sportclub silvolde hoofdklasse"
        },
        {
            "title": "IMG_9450",
            "link": "http://www.flickr.com/photos/sportclubsilvolde/21747302606/",
            "media": {
                "m": "http://farm1.staticflickr.com/630/21747302606_25769a18bd_m.jpg"
            },
            "date_taken": "2015-09-27T15:51:48-08:00",
            "description": " <p><a href=\"http://www.flickr.com/people/sportclubsilvolde/\">SportclubSilvolde</a> posted a photo:</p> <p><a href=\"http://www.flickr.com/photos/sportclubsilvolde/21747302606/\" title=\"IMG_9450\"><img src=\"http://farm1.staticflickr.com/630/21747302606_25769a18bd_m.jpg\" width=\"240\" height=\"160\" alt=\"IMG_9450\" /></a></p> ",
            "published": "2015-09-28T02:59:37Z",
            "author": "nobody@flickr.com (SportclubSilvolde)",
            "author_id": "124810748@N04",
            "tags": "iris copyright sports soccer be quick epping voetbal 2015 1887 sportclub silvolde hoofdklasse"
        },
        {
            "title": "IMG_9173",
            "link": "http://www.flickr.com/photos/sportclubsilvolde/21773454925/",
            "media": {
                "m": "http://farm1.staticflickr.com/650/21773454925_6b011fa56b_m.jpg"
            },
            "date_taken": "2015-09-27T14:59:05-08:00",
            "description": " <p><a href=\"http://www.flickr.com/people/sportclubsilvolde/\">SportclubSilvolde</a> posted a photo:</p> <p><a href=\"http://www.flickr.com/photos/sportclubsilvolde/21773454925/\" title=\"IMG_9173\"><img src=\"http://farm1.staticflickr.com/650/21773454925_6b011fa56b_m.jpg\" width=\"240\" height=\"160\" alt=\"IMG_9173\" /></a></p> ",
            "published": "2015-09-28T02:59:28Z",
            "author": "nobody@flickr.com (SportclubSilvolde)",
            "author_id": "124810748@N04",
            "tags": "iris copyright sports soccer be quick epping voetbal 2015 1887 sportclub silvolde hoofdklasse"
        },
        {
            "title": "IMG_9369",
            "link": "http://www.flickr.com/photos/sportclubsilvolde/21773442385/",
            "media": {
                "m": "http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5776/21773442385_2fe8b59342_m.jpg"
            },
            "date_taken": "2015-09-27T15:43:08-08:00",
            "description": " <p><a href=\"http://www.flickr.com/people/sportclubsilvolde/\">SportclubSilvolde</a> posted a photo:</p> <p><a href=\"http://www.flickr.com/photos/sportclubsilvolde/21773442385/\" title=\"IMG_9369\"><img src=\"http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5776/21773442385_2fe8b59342_m.jpg\" width=\"240\" height=\"160\" alt=\"IMG_9369\" /></a></p> ",
            "published": "2015-09-28T02:59:35Z",
            "author": "nobody@flickr.com (SportclubSilvolde)",
            "author_id": "124810748@N04",
            "tags": "iris copyright sports soccer be quick epping voetbal 2015 1887 sportclub silvolde hoofdklasse"
        },
        {
            "title": "IMG_9252",
            "link": "http://www.flickr.com/photos/sportclubsilvolde/21773446605/",
            "media": {
                "m": "http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5803/21773446605_f7a06e7e36_m.jpg"
            },
            "date_taken": "2015-09-27T15:08:46-08:00",
            "description": " <p><a href=\"http://www.flickr.com/people/sportclubsilvolde/\">SportclubSilvolde</a> posted a photo:</p> <p><a href=\"http://www.flickr.com/photos/sportclubsilvolde/21773446605/\" title=\"IMG_9252\"><img src=\"http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5803/21773446605_f7a06e7e36_m.jpg\" width=\"240\" height=\"160\" alt=\"IMG_9252\" /></a></p> ",
            "published": "2015-09-28T02:59:33Z",
            "author": "nobody@flickr.com (SportclubSilvolde)",
            "author_id": "124810748@N04",
            "tags": "iris copyright sports soccer be quick epping voetbal 2015 1887 sportclub silvolde hoofdklasse"
        },
        {
            "title": "IMG_9338",
            "link": "http://www.flickr.com/photos/sportclubsilvolde/21585421430/",
            "media": {
                "m": "http://farm1.staticflickr.com/678/21585421430_990728e31c_m.jpg"
            },
            "date_taken": "2015-09-27T15:21:18-08:00",
            "description": " <p><a href=\"http://www.flickr.com/people/sportclubsilvolde/\">SportclubSilvolde</a> posted a photo:</p> <p><a href=\"http://www.flickr.com/photos/sportclubsilvolde/21585421430/\" title=\"IMG_9338\"><img src=\"http://farm1.staticflickr.com/678/21585421430_990728e31c_m.jpg\" width=\"240\" height=\"160\" alt=\"IMG_9338\" /></a></p> ",
            "published": "2015-09-28T02:59:35Z",
            "author": "nobody@flickr.com (SportclubSilvolde)",
            "author_id": "124810748@N04",
            "tags": "iris copyright sports soccer be quick epping voetbal 2015 1887 sportclub silvolde hoofdklasse"
        },
        {
            "title": "IMG_9186",
            "link": "http://www.flickr.com/photos/sportclubsilvolde/21747317326/",
            "media": {
                "m": "http://farm1.staticflickr.com/655/21747317326_09db2d4bc4_m.jpg"
            },
            "date_taken": "2015-09-27T15:00:37-08:00",
            "description": " <p><a href=\"http://www.flickr.com/people/sportclubsilvolde/\">SportclubSilvolde</a> posted a photo:</p> <p><a href=\"http://www.flickr.com/photos/sportclubsilvolde/21747317326/\" title=\"IMG_9186\"><img src=\"http://farm1.staticflickr.com/655/21747317326_09db2d4bc4_m.jpg\" width=\"240\" height=\"160\" alt=\"IMG_9186\" /></a></p> ",
            "published": "2015-09-28T02:59:29Z",
            "author": "nobody@flickr.com (SportclubSilvolde)",
            "author_id": "124810748@N04",
            "tags": "iris copyright sports soccer be quick epping voetbal 2015 1887 sportclub silvolde hoofdklasse"
        },
        {
            "title": "IMG_9366",
            "link": "http://www.flickr.com/photos/sportclubsilvolde/21761741452/",
            "media": {
                "m": "http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5691/21761741452_64bf400d37_m.jpg"
            },
            "date_taken": "2015-09-27T15:43:07-08:00",
            "description": " <p><a href=\"http://www.flickr.com/people/sportclubsilvolde/\">SportclubSilvolde</a> posted a photo:</p> <p><a href=\"http://www.flickr.com/photos/sportclubsilvolde/21761741452/\" title=\"IMG_9366\"><img src=\"http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5691/21761741452_64bf400d37_m.jpg\" width=\"240\" height=\"160\" alt=\"IMG_9366\" /></a></p> ",
            "published": "2015-09-28T02:59:35Z",
            "author": "nobody@flickr.com (SportclubSilvolde)",
            "author_id": "124810748@N04",
            "tags": "iris copyright sports soccer be quick epping voetbal 2015 1887 sportclub silvolde hoofdklasse"
        },
        {
            "title": "IMG_9193",
            "link": "http://www.flickr.com/photos/sportclubsilvolde/21152397043/",
            "media": {
                "m": "http://farm1.staticflickr.com/667/21152397043_119c967606_m.jpg"
            },
            "date_taken": "2015-09-27T15:00:38-08:00",
            "description": " <p><a href=\"http://www.flickr.com/people/sportclubsilvolde/\">SportclubSilvolde</a> posted a photo:</p> <p><a href=\"http://www.flickr.com/photos/sportclubsilvolde/21152397043/\" title=\"IMG_9193\"><img src=\"http://farm1.staticflickr.com/667/21152397043_119c967606_m.jpg\" width=\"240\" height=\"160\" alt=\"IMG_9193\" /></a></p> ",
            "published": "2015-09-28T02:59:30Z",
            "author": "nobody@flickr.com (SportclubSilvolde)",
            "author_id": "124810748@N04",
            "tags": "iris copyright sports soccer be quick epping voetbal 2015 1887 sportclub silvolde hoofdklasse"
        },
        {
            "title": "IMG_9031",
            "link": "http://www.flickr.com/photos/sportclubsilvolde/21585604338/",
            "media": {
                "m": "http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5759/21585604338_75455ba520_m.jpg"
            },
            "date_taken": "2015-09-27T14:42:39-08:00",
            "description": " <p><a href=\"http://www.flickr.com/people/sportclubsilvolde/\">SportclubSilvolde</a> posted a photo:</p> <p><a href=\"http://www.flickr.com/photos/sportclubsilvolde/21585604338/\" title=\"IMG_9031\"><img src=\"http://farm6.staticflickr.com/5759/21585604338_75455ba520_m.jpg\" width=\"240\" height=\"160\" alt=\"IMG_9031\" /></a></p> ",
            "published": "2015-09-28T02:59:27Z",
            "author": "nobody@flickr.com (SportclubSilvolde)",
            "author_id": "124810748@N04",
            "tags": "iris copyright sports soccer be quick epping voetbal 2015 1887 sportclub silvolde hoofdklasse"
        },
        {
            "title": "IMG_9103",
            "link": "http://www.flickr.com/photos/sportclubsilvolde/21585435240/",
            "media": {
                "m": "http://farm1.staticflickr.com/663/21585435240_a5757ed8fd_m.jpg"
            },
            "date_taken": "2015-09-27T14:49:37-08:00",
            "description": " <p><a href=\"http://www.flickr.com/people/sportclubsilvolde/\">SportclubSilvolde</a> posted a photo:</p> <p><a href=\"http://www.flickr.com/photos/sportclubsilvolde/21585435240/\" title=\"IMG_9103\"><img src=\"http://farm1.staticflickr.com/663/21585435240_a5757ed8fd_m.jpg\" width=\"240\" height=\"160\" alt=\"IMG_9103\" /></a></p> ",
            "published": "2015-09-28T02:59:28Z",
            "author": "nobody@flickr.com (SportclubSilvolde)",
            "author_id": "124810748@N04",
            "tags": "iris copyright sports soccer be quick epping voetbal 2015 1887 sportclub silvolde hoofdklasse"
        },

        },
        }
    ]
}
```

my logcat

```
10-05 10:11:19.821: E/AndroidRuntime(1731): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.squareup.picasso.Picasso
10-05 10:11:19.821: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at com.suni.sun.CustomListViewAdapter.getView(CustomListViewAdapter.java:46)
10-05 10:11:19.821: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2159)
10-05 10:11:19.821: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1246)
10-05 10:11:19.821: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1158)
10-05 10:11:19.821: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
10-05 10:11:19.821: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:666)
10-05 10:11:19.821: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:477)
10-05 10:11:19.821: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15518)
10-05 10:11:19.821: E/AndroidRuntime(1731):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4825)
```

Comment: where is your logcat??

Comment: You need to add the class `com.squareup.picasso.Picasso` to your project.

Answer (score 2):

You have forgotten to add this line to your build.properties file

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

As explained in the [Picasso documentation](http://square.github.io/picasso/) that's what enables your project to use the library/

Comment: I see from your other answer that you are using Eclipse and and android studio. Will be so kind as to strip out some of the excess code from the question, maybe even the json part and add your project.properties file.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using gradle add this line to your build.gradle under the dependency

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
```

else download the jar from maven central ot jcenter

Comment: after downloading the jar did you add it in your lib folder by right clicking project.

Comment: no I add it by right clicking on myapp and move to properties and then javabuild path and add external jars and I browse it.

Comment: In that java build path there is a last tab you have to check (select this jar) did this too

Comment: what last tab I have to check

Comment: in order and export tab tick that picasso